# Создание chm-файлов

Tags: документация, chm

Хочу сделать документацию к своей программе. Не документирование кода, а мануал для пользователя. Решил сделать в chm-файле. Не подскажете, как создать такой файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удобная прога - [Help & Manual](http://www.ec-software.com/products_hm_screenshots.html)

[Создание файла помощи CHM с помощью Help & Manual](http://for-software-testers.blogspot.com/2008/06/chm-help-manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

Есть бесплатная прога от MS - HTML Help Workshop.
Еще есть htm2chm, тоже бесплатная, работает по принципу архиватора.