# Документация пользователя

Tags: документация

Какие способы создания справки для пользователя программы вы знаете?

Comment: Вопрос заключается не как генерить chm-файлы, а об альтереативах данному подходу.

Comment: Лучше редактировать вопрос, вместо добавления комментария.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать HTML-страницы. Браузеры сейчас установлены на большей части компов.

Comment: Не подскажите программу для создания такого рода справки

Comment: А вам под какую ОС -- Windows, Linux или Mac OS X?

Comment: Под Windows, но кросс-платформенное решение будет лучше.

Comment: Любой hTML-редактор подойдет, т.к. это не CHM-формат а просто набор файлов *.html, которые открываются в браузере. 

Под Windows  я раньше использовал Adobe Dreamveawer, т.к. в нем и визуальное редактирование и редактор кода совмещены. Под Linux  виуальных редакторов мало Кроссплатформенных я не видел.

Ещё как вариант формата для документации можно использовать PDF, но он по сравнению с HTML на мой взгляд имеет недостаток -- навигацию сложно сделать (по разделам, документ то один).

Answer (score 1):

Уже ответил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-chm-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1):

> Какие способы создания справки для пользователя программы вы знаете?

Для пользователя? Открываете любой текстовый редактор и набиваете. В любом случае, первично - "мясо", затравка документа. А потом можно уже навернуть красивости: оглавление, форматирование, картинки и пр. Причем вариантов как сохранить документацию масса: начиная от обычных txt-файлов, кончая навороченными CHM и PDF. Посмотрите как сделано у других и решите, что лучше подходит Вам лично. Напомню, что стандартная справка в Windows реализуется через HLP-файлы (уже уходят в прошлое) и CHM-файлы (по сути - архив с HTML-документами). PDF же очень легко получить из RTF, DOC или ODT (OpenOffice)-документа.

В автоматическом же режиме удастся сделать "документацию для программиста": описание внутреннего мира программы, который нужен при ее доработке. Да и то это возможно только при комментировании кода по определенному стандарту, чтобы эти комментарии легко было найти и обработать автоматизированными утилитами.